# How to implement state url in Framework7?

Tags: angularjs, html-framework-7

I would like to Develop hybrid application by using Framework7. I started earlier with Get Started in [Framework7](http://framework7.io) Website.

Basically my concern is about, i have login and registration pages when app launches. Moreover throughout my app its using RESTFULL webservices.

Can anyone suggest me with the architecture, Its capable of something like i have to keep common data in one place and how to i redirect the app when successful login(State URL's) etc.,

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Please follow this link http://framework7.io/docs/init-app.html#example-with-preroute